# Avoid concurrent SSL/TLS negotiation of first request and subsequent resource

Tags: ssl, browser, ssl-certificate, rendering, tls1.2

I configured an instance on MS Azure and implemented a SSL certificate to the domain. When I tested performance (on 3G), I noticed that the SSL negotiation is happening on two requests concurrently, which (unnecessarily) prolongs the process and results in a 0.6s time to complete.

[image: Webpagetest Screenshot here]

Does anyone have a tip how to solve/avoid this? It's adding an extra 0.3 seconds to the rendering path and I feel it can be avoided.

Comment: Using parallel connections is a feature of the browser and you cannot stop it from the server side. Also, what in the graph makes you think that parallel SSL handshakes slows down the process to get all resources? I only see a speedup since after loading the initial page '/' it now loads the embedded resources 'x.png' and 't.jpg' in parallel.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks for your quick response! I'd say since its doing the socket connect + TLS handshake in parallel on the first and third request, bandwidth is split and hence takes longer to complete. It would make more sense to only do this on the 1st request and then continue with parallel connections for additional resources.

Comment: In most scenarios the TLS handshake is latency bound not bandwidth bound. This might be different if you have a low latency low bandwidth connection but I don't think that 3G counts as such. But again, this is how browsers behave and you cannot control it from the server.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich This is a good point. Thanks for helping me out here and the latency/bandwidth differentiation makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

I would look closely on 'SSL/TLS Sessions' - this is exactly what you need to decrease the negotiations time. Do not confuse them with HTTP sessions.